# revert the git last commit and apply it to github for deployment scripts

Tags: git, github

We made a commit recently which we need to revert. We were able to successfully revert this change and apply it to GitHub doing the following

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push -f
```

The problem is, our deployment script is rejecting the changes. The way our deployment scripts work is, they pull from the development branch and merge it with the staging branch to reflect new changes following these steps

```
git checkout development
git pull
git checkout staging
git pull
git merge development # it is refusing to merge at this stage 
git push
```

Can anyone help on how we can revert the last commit and make it reachable for our deployment scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't merge with an ancestor of a commit. Either you are going to need to do a git revert and make a new commit, reverting the changes, or override the behavior of your deployment scripts somehow.

Comment: how can i do git revert to a specific git commit id?

Comment: Well, what `git revert <commit1> [<commit2> ... [<commitN>]]` does is revert the changes of a commit(s), so if there were multiple commits you would want to revert, you have to give all the command all of the commits you want to revert.

A better option would be to do git checkout to the commit you want as the new staging commit, then go `git reset --soft <current staging branch` and committing.